# How would I get rid of [(TEST,)]

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, tweepy, pgadmin

I need to pull an entry from a postgres database and post it to twitter. I've come up with the following (still very basic):

```
cur.execute("SELECT (tweet) from message ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1")
Tweet = cur.fetchall()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("BLABLABLA",
    "3kJBy5YzT2PoemdpBLABLABLABLAgrzGMVpPP6Eemlf")
auth.set_access_token("144493026BLABLABLABLABLACfMiBz57GuzPo",
    "fnCKbBLABLABLABLABLAeN2FnuTaR")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status(Tweet)
```

It works, but what ends up on twitter looks like:
[(TEST,)]

How do I get rid of those things?

Comment: What do you mean by "those things"?

Answer (score 2):

It is an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) of [tuples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp),

```
data = [(TEST,)]
print(data[0][0])
```

This should work

Comment: You may approve the answer if you found it satisfactory